# ARRAYS in C a hassle

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I have been trying to program a UNIX style shell command prompt in C. Within this program I need it to keep track of the commands that have already been used, so the user can recall the last command by entering 'r'. I made a globally initialized array to hold strings. Whenever the array of characters a user entered needs to be saved, I add it to the global array. I have tried memcpy, simply copying each value using a loop, and just copying the pointer. None of these have been working. I am not super familiar with C and I am sure it is a pointer problem.

Whenever I copy the pointer of inputBuffer to my global array string (it does get copied), however upon leaving the setup function this pointer disappears? I am not exactly sure what I am doing wrong.

Test:

> (1)user input --> ls
>
> string[0] = ls
>
> (2)user input --> r
>
> inputBuffer = ls
>
> string[recent] = ls
>
> incorrectly does...
>
> inputBuffer = r
>
> string[recent] = r

(I have included the relevant parts of the code.)

```
 #define MAX_LINE 80 /* 80 chars per line, per command, should be enough. */
    #define SAVED_BUFFER 100


    char *string[SAVED_BUFFER];
    int p = 0;
    int recent = -1;
    int stringSize = 0;

    void setup(char inputBuffer[], char *args[],int *background)
    {
        int length, /* # of characters in the command line *

        /* read what the user enters on the command line */
        length = read(STDIN_FILENO, inputBuffer, MAX_LINE);  

        start = -1;
        if (length == 0)
            exit(0);            /* ^d was entered, end of user command stream */
        if (length < 0){
            perror("error reading the command");
            exit(-1);           /* terminate with error code of -1 */
        }

        if (inputBuffer[0] == 'r' && inputBuffer[1] == '\n' && stringSize > 0) {
            int k;  

            memcpy(inputBuffer, string[recent], strlen(string[recent]) + 1);
            printf("%s",inputBuffer);
            printf("%s",string[recent]);

        }
        else {  

            string[p] = inputBuffer;
            printf("%s", string[0]);

            stringSize++;
            recent++; // one behind strings current array location, to get history
            p++; // current string array spot
        }

    }

    int main(void)
    {
        char inputBuffer[MAX_LINE]; /* buffer to hold the command entered */
        int background;             /* equals 1 if a command is followed by '&' */
        char *args[MAX_LINE/2+1];/* command line (of 80) has max of 40 arguments */


        while (1) {            /* Program terminates normally inside setup */
        background = 0;
        printf("COMMAND2->");

            fflush(0);

        setup(inputBuffer, args, &background);       /* get next command */
        }
    }
```

Comment: Yes, it's a hassle, but you don't really understand c until you "get" this problem automatically.

Comment: Yeah I kind of don't understand C...haha. I am trying to though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you "save the input buffer" you actually only store a pointer to the `inputBuffer` array:

```
string[p] = inputBuffer;
```

The actual data is not copied, you just store a pointer to the global input buffer. When the next input replaces the old content of `inputBuffer`, you will see the new content even if you access it through `string[recent]`.

The calls to `memcpy` don't actually do anything, since the passed input and output buffer all refer to the same memory.

To actually store a copy of the data you have to allocate new memory to store the copy. Since you are dealing with strings, this is most easily done with `strdup()`, which duplicates a string:

```
string[p] = strdup(inputBuffer);
```

Later, once you are done with such a copy and don't need it anymore you have to free the memory used by the copy:

```
free(string[p]);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This helped make it copy correctly. However for some reason it won't read in the command the same way.

if inputBuffer is used without getting it from string[recent], it works fine. When I use the copy from string[recent] it won't run or create the process. I printed what the two identical inputBuffers held and it was identical and so was there address.

Comment: Nevermind it was because I didn't change the length to reflect the change in inputbuffer. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried changing

```
char *string[SAVED_BUFFER];
```

to

```
char string[SAVED_BUFFER][MAX_LINE];
```

I think that's how you're treating it in the code

Comment: I will try this because I understand where you are coming from, but I tried it and could not get it to work. haha

Comment: It doesn't make any difference actually in how items are accessed

Comment: @BlackBear the first allocates a `SAVED_BUFFER` sized block of memory and `string` points to a pointer to the first character. In the second line, the compiler allocates a `SAVED_BUFFER * MAX_LINE` block.... Right?